# Why is onAppear method not working in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I wanted to get the API from the site and show it to the ContentView.
However, the function that receives the API that I wrote in the onAppear function attached to the List does not work.
So when access the array where you store the data, this app stops because it said you accessed nil.

```
var body: some View {
    Color.pink.opacity(0.2)
    List(weatherFetcher.weathers.first!.response.body.items.item, id: \.id) { weather in
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Text(weather.category)
                .font(.headline)
            Text(weather.fcstValue)
                .font(.subheadline)
        }
    }
    .onAppear {
        weatherFetcher.fetchWeathers() // Try BreakPoint
        print("Pass")
    }
}
```

I tried make breakpoint. However, the compiler passed the pew during debugging.
I also checked using print, but "Pass" did not appear in the console window.
Isn't the onAppear function running before the List appears?

Comment: don't use `!` `onAppear` will never run because you crash the app before the app has time to fetch. Always unwrap safely.

Comment: `first` is nil when the view is created. You need to unwrap it in a safe manner. Best solution is probably to do it in weatherFetcher so don’t need to a path like `weatherFetcher.weathers.first!.response.body.items.item`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key point lorem ipsum is making is that this line is evaluated **before** onAppear:

```
List(weatherFetcher.weathers.first!.response.body.items.item, id: \.id) { weather in
```

Then, if `onAppear` causes a `@State` value to be changed (or a `@Published` property that is being observed), then the body will be reevaluated.

You must handle the case where `weathers` is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably `weatherFetcher.fetchWeathers()` is an asynchronous call to retrieve some model data.  The desired behavior is that when the user navigates to this view, the weather data is loaded and displayed.  This means that you will need to add some empty state to display while the weather data is being fetched, such as a loader with a message.

Your `body` logic should account for this by having a branch for when `weatherFetcher.weathers` is empty/nil.  In that case, an empty state view will displayed instead of the List.  Once the view appears (initially displaying the empty state), the weather data will load and populate `weatherFetcher.weathers`, which property should be published by the `weatherFetcher` class.  The view will then respond to the published change and redraw, with the `body` logic displaying the list now that `weathers` is no longer nil.

Comment: Did ChatGTP tell you this?